# dim Pull data from lower variable to higher

Tags: vb.net

I have

```
 Dim m_LedgerList As New Ejm.Financial.Entities.LedgerList
    m_LedgerList = My.StaticData.LedgerList
    m_LedgerList.Filter = "LedgerfunctionID = 2"
```

but the filter i put on m_LedgerList.Filter pull trough to My.StaticData.LedgerList

Any idees how to stop the filter to go up?

Comment: You set the _m_LedgerList_ to reference the _My.StaticData.LedgerList_ so why are you surprised that a _filter_ acts on that data? If you don't want this to happen then you need to _copy_ the My.StaticData.LedgerList_ instead of setting a reference to it

Comment: sorry to bother you with something so basic but im stil a bit new to programming, how should i go about copying the data to m_LedgerList instead of putting it as a reference

Comment: What is the type of LedgerList?. If this is a list of some builtin types (int, strings) you could try to use the net CopyTo method, but if this is a class of your own you should implement yourself a Copy method that iterates through your class elements and create a new list of these elements with the data taken from the initial list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
m_LedgerList = My.StaticData.LedgerList
```

makes your variable *m_LedgerList* reference the same data referenced by the variable *My.StaticData.LedgerList*. This is not a copy, this is merely two variables that look at the same data in memory. Thus any action that you perform on the *m_LedgerList* variable acts on the same data seen by the *My.StaticData.LedgerList*.

If you want to have a different set of data then you need to duplicate the original data in a new memory location. This could be done inside the LedgerList class with something like this

```
Public Class LedgerList
     Public Function Duplicate() As LedgerList

           ' This create a new memory area for a new LedgerList
           Dim result = new LedgerList()

           ' Code to duplicate and add the elements in this 
           ' class to the new list

           return result                   
     End Function
End Class
```

Now you can go with

```
m_LedgerList = My.StaticData.LedgerList.Duplicate()
m_LedgerList.Filter = "LedgerfunctionID = 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ICloneable` as follows:

```
Class LedgerList
  Implements ICloneable

  Property Property1 As String
  Property Filter As String

  Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
    Dim myclone As New LedgerList
    myclone.Property1 = Me.Property1
    myclone.Filter = Me.Filter
    Return myclone
  End Function
End Class
```

Then to make a copy of your object:

```
 Dim m_LedgerList As Ejm.Financial.Entities.LedgerList = DirectCast(My.StaticData.LedgerList.Clone, Ejm.Financial.Entities.LedgerList)
 m_LedgerList.Filter = "LedgerfunctionID = 2"
```

Comment: Yes, that was a recommended way to go in NET 1.1. Nowadays ICloneable interface is deprecated for various reason.

Comment: True! I missed that memo